# Reading the multi line in column data from CSV using java

Tags: java

When I tried to read multi line data in column from CSV file using java program then It doesn't provide the work, I used buffered Reader for this

I used buffered Reader for this

```
private static List<Book> readBooksFromCsv(String fileName) {
        List<Book> books=new ArrayList<>();
        Path filePath=Paths.get(fileName);
        try {
            BufferedReader br=Files.newBufferedReader(filePath,StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
            String  line=br.readLine();
            while(line!=null)
            {
                String []attribute=line.split(",");
                Book book=createBook(attribute);
                books.add(book);
                line=br.readLine();
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return books;
    }

    private static Book createBook(String[] attribute) {

        int transactionId=Integer.parseInt(attribute[0]);
        int caseId=Integer.parseInt(attribute[1]);
        String lastName=attribute[2];
        return new Book(transactionId,caseId,lastName);

    }
```

Wants a solution to for the above problem

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the csv file that contains multi-line entries? I think multiline is an anti-pattern for csv files...

Comment: You can parse csv header and calculate count of attributes. After this you can read lines until count of attributes will be enough. And after this call ```createBook```.

Comment: An example of the csv file would indeed be of great help

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use a CSV parsing library, or modify how you're reading data. Take a look at [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

It is possible and valid for a single CSV record to contain one or more values that have one or more line breaks. Your code above assumes that each CSV record contains no line breaks.

For example, your code would handle this:

```
Sally Smith,123,F
```

However, your code would interpret the following as two separate CSV records – one that contains a single value `Jeff`, and another that contains three values `Johnson,333,M` instead of seeing a single record of three values, where the first value includes a line break:

```
Jeff
Johnson,333,M
```